# Adjectival form of "degrade"?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, derivational-morphology

For example, I want to say:

> This book degrades Western culture.

In this form:

> This book has been described as *???* to Western culture.

What would the adjectival form be? Is "degradeful" a word, or is there something better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commonest way of employing a verb as an adjective with an active sense—that is, with the sense that the noun modified is something which performs the action of the verb—is to use the present participle: the *-ing* form:

> This book has been described as **degrading** to Western culture.

Likewise, the commonest way of employing a verb as an adjective with a passive sense , in which the noun modified is something which suffers the action of the verb, is to use the past participle:

> **Degraded** Western culture is incapable of responding to the literary glories of the classics.